# Component rendered then disappears (react/redux/Firebase)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to fetch data from firebase, then update the state of the app with the results and display the data as a list in a list component.

Everything works except the final list component displays it and immediately becomes blank again.  After debugging, I found out it doesn't manage to correctly map the state to the props but I couldn't figure out how to achieve this. Thanks in advance

**PlantList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PlantSummary from './PlantSummary';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchMyPlants } from '../../store/actions/myPlantsActions'

var i =0;

class PlantList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { myPlants: []} ;
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("componentDidMount() triggered & state",i,this.state);
        console.log("componentDidMount() triggered & props ",i,this.props);
        this.props.dispatch(fetchMyPlants());
    }

    render(){
    i = i +1;
    console.log("render()"+i,this.props,this.state);
    const { myPlants } = this.props;
        return(
            <div className="plant-list section">
                {myPlants && myPlants.map((plant) => {
                    return (
                        <Link to={'/plant/'+ plant.id}>
                            <PlantSummary plant={plant} key={plant.id} />
                        </Link>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("mapStateToProps triggered",state);
    return {
        myPlants: state.myPlants.items
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PlantList)
```

**myPlantActions.js**

```
export const FETCH_MY_PLANTS_BEGIN = 'FETCH_MY_PLANTS_BEGIN';
export const FETCH_MY_PLANTS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_MY_PLANTS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_MY_PLANTS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_MY_PLANTS_FAILURE';

export const fetchMyPlantsBegin = () => ({
  type: FETCH_MY_PLANTS_BEGIN
});

export const fetchMyPlantsSuccess = myPlants => ({
  type: FETCH_MY_PLANTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: { myPlants }
})

export const fetchMyPlantsFailure = err => ({
  type: FETCH_MY_PLANTS_FAILURE,
  payload: { err }
});

export const fetchMyPlants = () => {
    return(dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
        dispatch(fetchMyPlantsBegin());
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        const authID = getState().firebase.auth.uid;

        const usersPlants = [];
        firestore.collection('users').doc(authID).collection('myPlants').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                firestore.collection('plants').doc(doc.data().id).get().then(
                    function(document) {
                        if (document.exists) {
                            const docToPushId = {id: doc.data().id};
                            let docToPush = {
                                ...docToPushId,
                                ...document.data()
                            };
                            usersPlants.push(docToPush);
                        } else {
                            console.log("No such document!");
                        }
                    }).catch(function(error) {
                        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                    }
                );

            });
        }).then(myPlants => {
            console.log("Dispatch happens now:",usersPlants);
            dispatch(fetchMyPlantsSuccess(usersPlants));
            return myPlants;
          }).catch(error => dispatch(fetchMyPlantsFailure(error)));

    }
};
```

**myPlantsReducer.js**

```
import {
    FETCH_MY_PLANTS_BEGIN,
    FETCH_MY_PLANTS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_MY_PLANTS_FAILURE
  } from '../actions/myPlantsActions';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
};

export default function myPlantsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
  case 'FETCH_MY_PLANTS_BEGIN':
    return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null
    };
case 'FETCH_MY_PLANTS_SUCCESS':
    return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        items: action.payload.myPlants
    };
case 'FETCH_MY_PLANTS_FAILURE':
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: false,
      error: action.payload.error,
      items: []
    };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**console logs**

[image: Console log]

Comment: Is there any console log you can share?

Comment: I've added screenshots and edited.

Comment: Maybe the redux deftools can provide more info, I don't see anything obviously wrong. Normally you'd start with dev tools to check the actions dispatched and the changes to the state that they are causing.

Comment: I tried a completely different approach now by fetching the data where the list is being instantiated and displaying it when the data is there. It's not working 100% well but it seems a bit better! Thanks however